# qsorting an array of class pointers

Tags: c++, class, qsort

I've read a lot of material on how to do this.  Unfortunately, they all resort to using something other than qsort (sort, usually).  However, this is impossible for me as I'm not allowed to use anything from the algorithm library.  I have to implement this from scratch, pretty much.  What I've got:

```
class String {
public:
        char* string;
        int size;

        String(char* string=0, int size=0) {
                this->string = string;
                this->size = size;
        }
        ~String() {
                delete [] string;
        }
};

int compare(void* obj1, void* obj2) {
        String* str1 = ((String*) obj1)->getColumn(column);
        String* str2 = ((String*) obj2)->getColumn(column);

        int i = strcmp(str1->string, str2->string);

        delete str1;
        delete str2;

        return i;
}

class ArrayList {
        int count;
        int arraySize;
public:
        String** list;
        ArrayList() {
                count = 0;
                arraySize = 10;
                list = new String*[arraySize];
        }
        ~ArrayList() {
                while(size()) {
                        delete remove();
                }
        }
        void add(String* s) {
                if(count==arraySize)
                        grow();

                list[count++] = s;
        }

        String* remove() {
                return list[count--];
        }

        String* get(int i) {
                return list[i];
        }

        int size() {
                return count;
        }
private:
        void grow() {
                String** temp = new String*[arraySize*=2];

                for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                        temp[i] = list[i];
                }

                delete [] list;

                list = temp;
        }
};
```

And my (current) call to qsort, though I've tried many combinations:

```
qsort(list->list, list->size, sizeof(String**), compare);
```

The error I ALWAYS get, not matter what I pass:

```
argument of type ‘int (ArrayList::)()’ does not match ‘size_t’
```

The code I've copied here doesn't include everything, but I've verified that all of the pieces work as intended, so don't worry about missing methods and such.

Comment: Learning C++ and not being allowed to use the standard library is like going to running school and being taught that "we're starting from the basics, so you're only allowed to use your left leg". Not the fault of the OP, of course, but rather his teacher.

Comment: Oh, we are allowed to use the standard library, just not for this project.  In the next project we can use strings instead of cstrings, and the project after that we can use the standard library.  He just wants us to learn in some depth what we are doing.  This isn't an introductory course to programming, it's a programming concepts class and we happen to use C++.

Comment: `qsort` is exactly like `std::sort`, except for some nasty casts that serve no purpose but to cause needless confusion in students.

Comment: Turns out I got the casts right first try, except that I didn't know they needed to be `const`.  I haven't struggled with C++ very much, for some reason I just couldn't see the `size` issue.  On the other hand, I already know PHP and Java, and have dealt with a bit of C before, but it was for a specific embedded system.  I think you all have a little lack of faith in students :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `list->size` instead of `list->size()`. The code should be:

```
qsort(list->list, list->size(), sizeof(String**), compare);
```

Comment: . . . seriously?  All the different combinations I could think of and I simply forgot `()`? Doh!  It gave me another error about my comparator not using `const void*`, but that was easy enough. Thank you, thank you!